# issues with updating labels from functions in tkinter python 3.8.2

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I've been teaching myself some tkinter to start building some real apps, and my first project is to build an interface for the Courera's all-too-famous Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock game.

Up to now I have all the buttons working fine enough (even though I feel like they are not updating anything if i repeatedly click on the same button without changing choice, as the result of the match never changes) and the result panel also works. that's what's makng me crazy, as far as I can see, the win counters and the computer choice panel follow the same logic and for some reason are not updating when I click a button. any hints?

Thanks already for the patience, and code as follows

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
from functools import partial

#setting the window early as I had issues and bugs when called after defining functions
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('350x200')

#global variables
result= tk.StringVar()
result.set("")
comp = tk.IntVar()
guess = tk.StringVar()
guess.set("")
playerWin = tk.IntVar()
playerWin.set(0)
compWin = tk.IntVar()
compWin.set(0)

#function that handles the computer's play in each game
def compPlay():
    global guess, comp
    comp.set(random.randrange(0,5))
    if comp.get()== 0:
        guess.set("Rock")
    elif comp.get()== 1:
        guess.set("Spock")
    elif comp.get() == 2:
        guess.set("Paper")
    elif comp.get() == 3:
        guess.set("Lizard")
    elif comp.get() == 4:
        guess.set("Scissors")

#function to play human vs computer choices and see who wins
def gameplay(playerNum,compNum):
    global result, comp, playerWin, compWin
    if playerNum == comp.get():
        result.set("It's a tie!")
    elif (playerNum - comp.get()) % 5 <= 2:
        result.set("Player wins!")
        playerWin = playerWin.get() + 1
    elif (playerNum - comp.get()) % 5 >= 3:
        result.set("Computer wins!")
        compWin += compWin.get() + 1
    else:
        result.set(text = "")
        
# game title
lblGame= tk.Label(text="Rock, Scissors, Paper, Lizard, Spock").pack()

#frame with the buttons for player choices
playerFrame = tk.Frame(window)
btRock = tk.Button(playerFrame, text = "Rock", width = 15, command = partial(gameplay, 0,compPlay)).pack()
btScissors = tk.Button(playerFrame, text = "Scissors", width = 15, command = partial(gameplay, 1,compPlay)).pack()
btPaper = tk.Button(playerFrame, text = "Paper", width = 15, command = partial(gameplay, 2,compPlay)).pack()
btLizard = tk.Button(playerFrame, text = "Lizard", width = 15, command = partial(gameplay, 3,compPlay)).pack()
btSpock = tk.Button(playerFrame, text = "Spock", width = 15, command = partial(gameplay, 4,compPlay)).pack()
playerFrame.pack(side = tk.LEFT)

#frame with info about the game, as in what the computer chose and the result of the play
compFrame = tk.Frame(window)
lbComp = tk.Label(compFrame, text = "Computer plays:").pack()
lbGuess = tk.Label(compFrame, textvariable = guess, relief = tk.GROOVE, borderwidth = 5, width = 15).pack()
lbRes = tk.Label(compFrame, text = "and the result of the game is").pack()
lbMatch = tk.Label(compFrame, textvariable = result, relief = tk.GROOVE, borderwidth = 5, width = 15).pack()

#mini frames for score keeping
playerFrame = tk.Frame(compFrame, relief = tk.GROOVE, borderwidth = 3)
playerSide = tk.Label(playerFrame, text = "Player points:").pack()
playerScore = tk.Label(playerFrame, textvariable = str(playerWin)).pack()
playerFrame.pack(side = tk.LEFT)

compScoreFrame = tk.Frame(compFrame, relief = tk.GROOVE, borderwidth = 3)
compSide = tk.Label(compScoreFrame, text = "Computer points:").pack()
compScore = tk.Label(compScoreFrame, textvariable = str(compWin)).pack()
compScoreFrame.pack(side = tk.RIGHT)

compFrame.pack(side = tk.RIGHT)

window.mainloop()
```

I get this error on the console whenever the game should give points to either player:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "~/Interactive Python/teste tkinter3.py", line 54, in gameplay
    playerWin = playerWin.get() + 1
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems that are not working properly here:

1. The **Computer plays** label field is not refreshing, because you never call the `compPlay()` function. This function should be called each time the player presses the left-hand button, but this function is unused in the `gameplay` method. Simply call this function to refresh the computer guess and set the value of a label.
2. In the `gameplay` function the `compWin` and `playerWin` objects are not `ints` but `tkinter.Intvar` so you should `set` their variables instead of using `+` and `+=`. This is the reason for this error.

Comment: I am unsure on how to add the call to compPlay() to the buttons, since that might mean a different "roll" of the random number that gets into the play.

While testing here I noticed that the call to comPlay() is not being done indeed since all the throws are getting the same results per button (rock always ties, paper and scissors always player wins, lizard and spock always computer wins). 

I take it I need to take compPlay out of the button command, but not sure where to put it...

Comment: Each button calls the `gameplay` method. So at the beginning of this method you might add the `compPlay()` invocation.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `playWin` is a `tkinter.Intvar` object,you need to change the function `gameplay` to:

```
def gameplay(playerNum, compNum):
    global result, comp, playerWin, compWin
    if playerNum == comp.get():
        result.set("It's a tie!")
    elif (playerNum - comp.get()) % 5 <= 2:
        result.set("Player wins!")
        playerWin.set(playerWin.get() + 1)
    elif (playerNum - comp.get()) % 5 >= 3:
        result.set("Computer wins!")
        compWin.set(compWin.get() + 1)
    else:
        result.set(text="")
```